# Excel Macro during open process

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to write a macro to turn the multi select on for a slicer when the workbook is opened. The macro works if I run it manually but does nothing when I open the file. Can someone help figure out what is missing?

```
Sub Auto_Open()

Sheets("Field HC Report").Activate

ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Reporting Country")).Select
SendKeys "%s"
DoEvents

End Sub
```

Thanks,
Amy

UPDATE: Putting it in Workbook_Open() and in the workbook rather than module made it work. Thank you Samuel and Kin! One other question, how would I modify this if my file is password protected to be read only for other users? I would like the macro to run even when users open it as read-only. – Amy

Comment: Have you put your executable code in the `Workbook_Open()` event (rather than `Auto_Open()` )? **Note:** when using sheet or workbook events, don't rename the event handler to match the name of your worksheet/workbook etc.

Comment: put the `Sub Workbook_Open()` in your workbook rather than module, then it will work

Comment: Putting it in Workbook_Open() and in the workbook rather than module made it work. Thank you both! One other question, how would I modify this if my file is password protected to be read only for other users? I would like the macro to run even when users open it as read-only.